# Trying to run Virtualbox through TOR middlebox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, tor

i REALLY need some help before my laptop goes through the wall.

I want to run a virtual machine through tor middlebox. I want the entire VM`s connection to go through the tor network. (Im wanting to setup my hidden service and for my needs this will work best)

I started by looking here - http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-tor-middlebox-routing-all-virtualbox-virtual-machine-traffic-over-the-tor-network

I know this is old but i figured i`d give it a go anyway.

For reference my Host machine is running Ubuntu 13.04 and the VM will be running 12.04LTS. On virtualbox

Well i have tor installed as per the guide, i have gone though the setup steps. But it didnt work. My VM will not connect to the net. I checked ifconfig and i am recieving an ip address, but i cant get a connection to the web to check i am running through tor.

I`ve spent a good few hours on this but i cant get it working, im just at point and click mode now. Looked at so many sites, and almost all of them point back to the original. I have tried tweaking the settings, and looked at numerous forums. But i cant get this working.

If i try using the tor browser bundle, it refuses to start tor, stating the it hasn`t got permission or cant listen on 172.16.0.1:53. tried using vidalia bundle for the tor install but that refuses to find the tor exec (not really an issue)

Here are the settings i am trying to run with...

/etc/network/interfaces

```
as stated in guide
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=vnet0
listen-address=192.168.1.1
dhcp-range=172.16.0.2,172.16.0.254,1h
```

/etc/tor/torrc

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 172.16.0.1
TransListenAddress 192.168.1.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 172.16.0.1
DNSListenAddress 192.168.1.1
```

middlebox.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# destinations you don't want routed through Tor 
NON_TOR="192.168.1.0/24 192.168.0.0/24"

# the UID Tor runs as
TOR_UID="109"

# Tor's TransPort
TRANS_PORT="9040"

# your internal interface
INT_IF="vnet0"

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $TOR_UID -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
for NET in $NON_TOR; do
 iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $NET -j RETURN
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INT_IF -d $NET -j RETURN
done

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANS_PORT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INT_IF -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INT_IF -p udp -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INT_IF -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANS_PORT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
for NET in $NON_TOR 127.0.0.0/8; do
 iptables -A OUTPUT -d $NET -j ACCEPT
done
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $TOR_UID -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this article help you? http://www.mike-warren.com/articles/routing-vm-traffic-through-tor.html

The short version is:

1. host runs a tun/tap device
2. host runs a VDE switch (which puts packets from the VM into the tap device)
3. host has iptables NAT rules to shovel tap device traffic into Tor
4. host runs Tor as transparent proxy
5. VM has static IP, connected to VDE switch

Instead of all that, you could run TAILS instead. https://tails.boum.org/

Comment: Thought of tails already, but tails is straight from the DVD only, too much hastle and messing about to try get a solid hdd install. For what im wanting, i need a VM set to access TOR only. Thanks though, gonna check that page out

Answer (score 0):

Consider running tails as vm guest.
Use a vm snapshot to avoid booting from tails live dvd (iso)